# Derivative of Dirac delta distribution

Tags: calculus, derivatives, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

How is the derivative of $\delta(x-y)$ with respect to $x$ related to the derivative with respect to $y$? I suspect they differ by a minus sign but I'm not sure.

Both $x$ and $y$ are real variables.

Comment: You're correct;  They differ by a minus sign.

Comment: The Dirac delta is emphatically *not* a function.

Comment: @math1000 Correct.  It IS a Generalized Function.  And its derivative as a distribution is well defined.

Comment: Thanks @MarkViola and Math1000. Now I have some ideas of distributions. Could you give a hint how to go about proving it?

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $$\delta(x\!-\!y), \quad\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\delta(x\!-\!y)\quad\text{and}\quad \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\delta(x\!-\!y)\tag{A}$$ 
are informal kernel notations for the  [distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) $$u,u_x,u_y~\in~ D^{\prime}(\mathbb{R}^2)\tag{B}$$ defined as

$$u[f]~:=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\!\mathrm{d}z~f(z,z),\quad u_x[f]~:=-\int_{\mathbb{R}}\!\mathrm{d}z~\frac{\partial f(z,z)}{\partial x},\quad u_y[f]~:=-\int_{\mathbb{R}}\!\mathrm{d}z~\frac{\partial f(z,z)}{\partial y},\tag{C}$$

respectively, for testfunctions $f\in D(\mathbb{R}^2)$. Here $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ mean the partial derivative of $f$ wrt. 1st and 2nd entry, respectively.

In this notation OP wants to prove that $$u_x+u_y~=~0.\tag{D}$$ 
*Proof of eq. (D):*

$$u_x[f]+u_y[f]~=~-\int_{\mathbb{R}}\!\mathrm{d}z~\frac{df(z,z)}{d z}
~=~f(-\infty,-\infty)-f(\infty,\infty)~=~0, \tag{E}$$
because the testfunction $f$ vanishes at infinity.

Comment: Thanks. Though I'll have to go through the concept of distributions to understand your proof since I come from a physics background :)